# AS3 Error 2025 The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller

Tags: actionscript-3

Edit: I didn't exactly know what I fiddled with, but it works now. I am considering taking down this post since there isn't an answer. The problem may not be with error 2025 entirely, as I was just removing code from other functions, and it just worked. Sorry.

I am relatively new to AS3, that i'm coding within the timeline, and I want to ask why 'removeChild(partsArr[i]); is not considered as a child? For context, I am making a snake game, and the following code removes all the sprites. I think the error specifically points out to the partsArr[i], but I am not exactly too familiar with children and parents. I left some out so you're not left with long code.

Here is a snippet:

```
var partsArr:Array = new Array(); //holds Snake’s head and body parts

function ini():void
{
    //Get and place snake’s head from the library

    head = new Head();

    addChild(head);

    //Push Snake’s head into parts array

    partsArr.push(head);

    //head’s random position for every new start

    headX = Math.ceil(((stage.stageWidth-headWidth)/(headWidth))*Math.random())*headWidth;

    headY = Math.ceil((((stage.stageHeight-hudHeight) - headWidth)/(headWidth))*Math.random())*headWidth;
}

function newFood():void
{
    foodX = Math.ceil(((stage.stageWidth-foodWidth)/(foodWidth))*Math.random())*foodWidth;

    foodY = Math.ceil((((stage.stageHeight-hudHeight)-foodWidth)/(foodWidth))*Math.random())*foodWidth;

    food.x = foodX - foodWidth/2;

    food.y = foodY - foodWidth/2;

    //Find new position each time when food is overlapping snake’s any body part

    for (var i:int = partsArr.length-1;i > 0; i--)
        {

            if(food.x == partsArr[i].x && food.y == partsArr[i].y)
            {
                newFood();
            }

            if(food.x == enemyfood.x && food.y == enemyfood.y) 
            {
                newFood();
            }
        
            if(food.x == dietfood.x && food.y == dietfood.y) 
            {
                newFood();
            }
        
            if(food.x == passfood.x && food.y == passfood.y) 
            {
                newFood();
            }

        }

}


function hideGrid(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Use tabs to keep your code structured and readable.
    if (WholeGrid)
    {
        WholeGrid.visible = false;
    }

    cleanup();

}

function cleanup():void
{
    removeChild(head);
    removeChild(food);
    removeChild(enemyfood);
    removeChild(dietfood);
    removeChild(passfood);
    removeChild(portal);

    for (var i:int = 0; i < partsArr.length; i++)

    {
        //Remove snake from the stage
        removeChild(partsArr[i]);
    }

    partsArr = [];
}
```

Comment: I assume you are working with the frame scripts. If you call **removeChild(A);** it is (in most caes) equal to **this.removeChild(A);** where **this** points to the **MovieClip** holding the timeline holding the frame with the given script. The object **A** must be a child of **this** object, you are not allowed to remove children not from their respective parents.

Comment: I am not too familiar with frame scripts or aware if i'm using one already. Anyways, does that mean I would have to declare partsArr as a parent? if yes, how so? like **'this.partsArr'**? or  as i've read a bit, this.partsArr = partsArr?

Comment: The script is frame script if you write it in the frame. The only other option is a class script that resides in a separate .as file.

Comment: You cannot declare **Array** to be a parent of anything. **Array** is a data structure. To understand display list, parents and children, please read this: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e26.html